# How to let Visual Studio to add references according to USINGS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference

I realized that when dividing a project into two in Visual Studio (2010) I'm still looking for references that are missing in the new project. Can Visual Studio do that for me? It can find all the namespaces I use so it should be easy for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built-in way to do this. However, you may want to check out the [PowerCommands extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) which gives you a "Copy Reference" command to quickly copy/paste assembly references between projects.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there's a way.